# RSpec crashing with multiple Rails validation helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard

I have two different validations for the :website attribute on my Customer model. One is the build in length helper, with the maximum set to 255, while the other is a custom validation. They both work individually, and the appropriate tests pass, but for some reason, when I run my tests with both validations, RSpec crashes to the point I have to complete exit out of Guard and restart it.

Here is my code, any way they are some how conflicting with each other? I have never experienced this before:

```
class Customer < Active Record::Base

  ...

  URL_REGEX = /(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i

  validates :website, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validate :valid_urls

  private
    def valid_urls
      ["website", "blog", "contact"].each do |attribute|
        errors.add(attribute, "needs to be a valid url") if send(attribute).present? && URL_REGEX.match(send(attribute)).nil?
      end
    end
end
```

UPDATE: Thanks for the help, turned out the whole issue was just a bad regex. I had copied the regex from a stackoverflow thread, which had escaped some of the ampersands, producing a bad regex. I just now copied it from the jQuery validate source and it worked, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Need some more info. What ruby/rails/rspec/guard versions are you using? Can you paste a crash backtrace (pastie.org would be fine)? What is the result of running the spec with guard turned off?

Comment: Hey gmile. ruby 1.9.2p290 // rails 3.2.11 // rspec 2.11.1 // guard 0.8.8. I unfortunately don't get a backtrace, it just stops running until I cancel out. I just ran it with guard turned off, and the exact same behavior happens. Once it hits my tests involving building a customer with website specified, it just stops dead in its tracks.

Comment: mackshkatz, can you try running the test without guard at all, to see if it works? Just `rspec spec/path/to/my_spec.rb`

Comment: gmile, sorry that is what I meant. I ran it with rspec, so it appears that Guard is not involved with the issue at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mackshkatz, can you try removing custom validation to use those provided by rails? As such:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :website, format: { with: URL_REGEX }, allow_blank: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :blog,    format: { with: URL_REGEX }, allow_blank: true
  validates :contact, format: { with: URL_REGEX }, allow_blank: true
end
```

And see if it passes? It seems like the problem may be in complex regexp you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the exact same behavior as well. Thanks for the efforts though.

Comment: Can you try it with some super dumb regexp instead? I have a suspicion that this may be a regexp problem. Also, can you try upgrading version of ruby, rails and rspec?

Comment: I made an update to my question, wasn't sure proper protocol when finding out the problem on my own, but the regex was bad. I had copied it from SO and the ampersands in it had been escaped, causing issues. So I just went and got it from the library's source. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: mackshkatz, would you mind accepting the answer then or close the question? Just to make it clear to other people that this has been solved

Comment: Yea, I'll accept your answer because it actually did clean up my validations quite a bit. Is there a standard action to do when I realize there was an unrelated solution, like in my case a bad regex? Or is updating my question like I did sufficient? Thanks gmile.

Comment: Usually you can just answer yourself and accept your own answer, if noone else have answered correctly.